# Transpose[m,{1,1}]

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, list-manipulation

According to the documentation, Transpose with a second argument {1,1} on a square matrix returns the diagonal of the matrix.

```
m = ArrayReshape[Range[25], {5, 5}];
Transpose[m, {1, 1}] == Diagonal[m]
(* True *)
```

Is it an arbitrary convention for the `Transpose` function, or does it correspond to some mathematical reality? It does not seem like an obvious consequence of the definition of transposition to me.

Comment: The documentation OP is referring to mentions this: _Transpose allows the $n_i$ to be repeated, computing diagonals of the subarrays determined by the repeated levels. The result is therefore an array of smaller depth._